# Picking up of multiple IDs together or individual ID in selenium

Tags: selenium, getelementbyid, element

Which is correct way to pick elements from HTML : pick up all ids on a page together or picking each ID individually?

Let me explain the scenario.
I have a HTML page with information associated to specific IDs, but IDs sometimes change according to the section they are being displayed into.
Now which approach is better, either to pick the all the ID's from the page and then adding checks to get the value or picking up of separate ID individually.
I also need to work with many IDs (20 out of 100) on the page at same time.

Please suggests.
Thanks

Comment: Do right click on Element , select Inspect Element option and that will give you exact id of specific element. If Ids of 2 elements are same then use XPATH to find element.

Comment: Instead of ID you can use xpath. Id's may change but xpath will not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an element is static, in that it will not change throughout the course of your test then there is no problem selecting it at the beginning. However i definetly feel that attempting to select all your elements at the beginnning is a bad idea. What happens if an element is not available until you have completed some action, NoSuchElementException. Or what about if you select an element and when you go to use it the element cant be found, StaleElementException.

So you definetly need to find a balance and select your elements at the aprropriate time. I saw some other suggestion above to use xpath as it will never change, again thats not true.It is also recommended in the documentation to first attempt to select by id and then name. Im sure there are alot of reasons for this but one that immediatley comes to mind is readibility, speed is also a factor.